# How to access type of class properties in dart

Tags: typescript, flutter, dart, types

In Typescript, you can obtain the type of the property of an object as below:

```
interface Animal {
  name: string,
  age: number
}

function sayName(name: Animal['name'] ) {}
```

In this way, we can keep the type requirements consistent across the codebase without restating the type of the expected parameter

Is there an equivalent way to access this in dart such that if I have a class as below:

```
class Todo {
  final String title;
}
```

I can type a function as such:

```
void saveTodo(Todo['title'] todoTitle){}
```

Comment: No, you cannot, in Dart, refer to the type of some field when defining the type of another field.